# React native Gesture response system does not work in IOS production

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-gesture-handler, react-native-ui-kitten

None of the modules that provide gesture capabilities work as expected in production IOS, they only work if you hold your finger lightly and slide very slowly over the element. All modules behave the same except for the `react-native-gesture-handler`, which is used by `react-navigation`.

UPD: My project uses `eva-design/eva`, `ui-kitten/components`, `ui-kitten/eva-icons`, `mobx`, `mobx-react`, `react-native-screens`, `react-navigation/drawer`, `react-navigation/native`, `react-navigation/stack`, `react-native-ux-cam`. I have suggestions that these modules may somehow affect this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research, I found the reason. After removing the `react-native-ux-cam`, gestures work adequately

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).